# Is it possible to automatically send render data each request?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to send data from my `config.js` file to every single render. Is there a way to do this with a few lines of code instead of having to manually push the data with every single render function?

Here's what I mean

```js
const data = require("config.js").coolData;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {data});
});

app.get("/request2", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {data);
});

app.get("/request3", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {foo, data);
});
```

Is there a way to easily send `data` to all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express, you can do it with `res.locals;` in a middleware For example:

```
const data = require("config.js").coolData;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.data = data;
    next();
});
...
```

Just be sure to place the middleware above before any other route

Comment: prob better in `app.locals` on boot, then its in both in `app.locals` and `res.app.locals` etc